# Does Nativescript's FlexboxLayout support `gap`?

Tags: nativescript

When using FlexboxLayout, it seems so easy to reach for `gap` to separate elements.

However, it seems it isn't supported, as it doesn't appear in https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/flexboxlayout. Is that the case? If so, what are some of the techniques to space out elements in a flex column or row?